# How can I copy generic collections in java?

Tags: java, generics

When I'm writing a generic collection like list, I met a problem. How can I make a copy constructor?
In cpp, I can use '*' to get the value of a pointer. So if item and new_item are pointers to generic type values, then simply use `*new_item = *item` to complete the copy. But in java, I can't copy generic variables so I can't make a copy constructor correctly.

```
public List(List<T> l) {
    this();
    _size = l._size;
    ListNode<T> l_node = l._head;
    ListNode<T> node = _head;
    while((l_node = l_node.next) != l._head) {
        node.next = new ListNode<T>(l_node.item, _head, node);
        node = node.next;
    }
}
```

This is the constructor of ListNode:

```
//this is incorrect
public ListNode(T item, ListNode<T> next, ListNode<T> prev) {
    this.item = item;
    this.next = next;
    this.prev = prev;
}
```

When generating a new node, I actually pass the address of l_node.item. So if I change elements in this new list, the old list will be changed.
Is there any way to generate a new node with the same value but different address?

Comment: If you have a `List<T>`, then you can make a new `List<T>` via `new ArrayList<>(yourList);`. The generics are inferable for the list as well. If you want to modify or read from this generic list, you'll be interested in java [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super) regarding `List<? extends T>` vs `List<? super T>`

Comment: ... A good point (that your `List<T>` is not `java.util.List<T>`). For the sake of a custom `List`, see how `ArrayList` was implemented: it uses `Object[]`/`Object` under the hood, as generic types are erased at runtime anyhow. These `Object`s are "unsafely" casted upon retrieval/storage, leading to a CCE if you start playing dirty with the generics.

Comment: You cannot copy the T, but you can have two nodes with independent references to the same T that can be independently changed.

Comment: Off-topic: By the way, what you call a "container" is referred to as a "[Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html)" in Java.

Comment: In C++, the elements of the container themselves have copy constructors. In Java, to do a deep copy, you would either have to use `item.clone()` (but then the class would need to implement `Cloneable` properly to get a true deep copy), or the class would have to have some other method, perhaps `.copy()` that would make a copy, and the list would have to limit itself to types that implement an interface with that, i.e. `List<T extends Copyable>`.

Comment: But I think the better approach would be to restrict yourself to lists of immutable objects and then you don't have to worry about the distinction between shallow and deep copies. Of course, that's not always possible. But I would strive to define my data model to make it possible.